# TypeError: Unable to build `Dense` layer with non-floating point dtype <dtype: 'string'> : My data has no String type data in it

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm trying to build a Neural Network for classification. I preprocessed all the data and it looks like this:
0.0 0.0  1.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 **2**   0.12436986167881312 -0.426405420419126  **1**

although everything looks okay and datatype is int or float but I'm still getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\spark\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 1002, in build
    'dtype %s' % (dtype,))

TypeError: Unable to build `Dense` layer with non-floating point dtype <dtype: 'string'>
```

Most features are dummies or scaled by standardscaler they are floats. and just to be sure I checked data type of last and 4th last column(which are integers in **Bold**) they are also integers. So..

why am I getting this error? how do I resolve this.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
pred_set = prediction_set.values
temp_dataset = np.concatenate([X, pred_set], axis=0)

'''Encoding Features'''
index_list = [1,2,4,6,7]
reverse_index = []
for i in range(len(index_list)):
    reverse_index.append(index_list[i]-temp_dataset.shape[1])
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
for i in range(len(reverse_index)):
    index = reverse_index[i]
    ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [index])], remainder = 'passthrough')
    temp_dataset = ct.fit_transform(temp_dataset)

X = temp_dataset[:891]
pred_set = temp_dataset[891:]

'''Train - Test split'''
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

'''Feature scaling'''
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
Xtrain[:, (-2,-3)] = sc.fit_transform(Xtrain[:, (-2,-3)])
Xtest[:, (-2,-3)] = sc.transform(Xtest[:, (-2,-3)])
pred_set[:, (-2,-3)] = sc.transform(pred_set[:, (-2,-3)])

Xtrain.astype(float)
Xtest.astype(float)
pred_set.astype(float)

import tensorflow as tf
classifier = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units= 20, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units= 20, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units= 1, activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

Comment: No sir!  that question has image data and I have numerical data. I actually tried to convert the column with int to floats with this : `df[-1].astype(float)` but it showed error that `int obj has no attribute astype`

Comment: @AustinSpark just a side note, why you scale after splitting? this might lead to some problems due to possible differences in train/test split, scaler can end up with slightly different scales for both parts of the dataset, you should do this before splitting. Same for any other operation you might repeat for both parts of the dataset, do it before split. If nothing else, you save time and code lines :)

Comment: I learned in my course of machine learning that scaling should be done after splitting the data bcos if you don't there are chances of what you call information leakage. And it make sense you know..if you scale along with Xtest the scaler is different. while if you scale train first and then apply `transform `method there is no consideration of Xtest it will only scale as per the scaler of Xtrain.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it was fit_transform and transform, my bad, makes absolutely sense, any update on the original problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast your data to float, works both with pandas or numpy:

```
df.astype(float)
```

According to comment, do not try to convert just a column, simply convert whole dataset.

In case there are some characters that are not digits, the following code should help:

```
df[-1] = pd.to_numeric(df[-1], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I tried it..seems to have no effect.. error is same and also after `df.astype(float)` the   integers are still integers they didn't turn to float. I'll edit the question n try to post a part my code if that might help.

Comment: @AustinSpark have you as well tried this: `df[-1] = pd.to_numeric(df[-1], errors='coerce')`
this will set possibly non-numeral characters to NaN

Comment: Just tried, still didn't work and got the same error.  I guess bcos there are no non-numerical values in the data. I tried SVM model and it worked just fine. But I wanted to use ANN and that's having this issue.

Comment: I can think of one more try, instead of `df[-1]` try `df.iloc[:,-1]`
As well `x_train.head` might help determine whats wrong